# How to do something else while one part of the program is waiting in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, api

I am trying to get weather data using OpenWeatherMap API in Python 3.9. But I can make only 60 calls/min. The moment I make all 60 calls, I'll have to put a delay for 60 seconds. Now, I want to do some other stuff during these 60 seconds, like saving the data I got into a database. What is the best way to achieve this?

Apologies if my question is not phrased correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet here would be *multithreading*.

Here are some good examples and tutorials:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-python-set-1/

In essence, multithreading allows you to divide your program up into multiple *threads*. Each of these threads can do work individually of one another until one thread *blocks* another thread.

Depending on what "stuff" you want to do you would design the connection between your API thread and your "do stuff while waiting" thread differently.